# injective homogeneous polynomial functions $p(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]:{\mathbb{N}}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Related to this question [Coefficients of $f(t)=(\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}e^{2\pi im^4t})(\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}e^{2 \pi inm^4t})$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198365/coefficients-of-ft-sum-m-0-inftye2-pi-im4t-sum-m-0-inftye)
I have the following question:

What is the set of homogeneous polynomials $p(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ wich induces injective function when viewed as polynomial functions $p:{\mathbb{N}}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: As with your preceding question, probabilistic heuristics (see e.g. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/the-probabilistic-heuristic-justification-of-the-abc-conjecture/ ) suggest such polynomials should be generically injective in degree 5 and higher but not in degree 4 or lower, at least for "typical" choices of polynomial $p$.  It may be possible to use the Bombieri-Lang conjecture to make the notion of "typical" precise (probably has to do with the the non-trivial component of the variety $p(x,y)=p(z,w)$ being of general type).

Comment: Somewhat related: it is an unsolved problem of Erdos to find a polynomial $p$ such that all the sums $p(a)+p(b)$, $0\le a<b$, are distinct. This is F30 in Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory.

Comment: @TerryTao: Thanks for the comment and for the reference. Gerry Myerson: Interesting! Thanks for the reference